# How can I add Where expressions to a LINQ query if I'm not sure which properties I'll want to match?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a situation where I might want to search by order number or by name. I know I can add a `Where` expression to my LINQ query, but I only want to add it for the property that I'm searching for! I won't know until the method is called which parameter will be provided, so how can I add the proper condition?

```
public JsonResult Search(int orderNo=0, string firstName="", string lastName="")
{
    if (orderNo >0){
        //add Condition
    }

    if (firstName.Length > 0){
        //add Condition
    }

    if (lastName.Length > 0){
        //add Condition
    }

    //get Result

    var result = Repository.Orders.Where(???).OrderByDescending(e=> e.orderNo);

    //return
}
```

Comment: Tried [expression trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your repository returns `IQueryable` you can compose your query however you want to:

```
var query = Repository.Orders;
if(orderNo > 0)
{
    query = query.Where( x => x.OrderId == orderNo);
}

if(firstName.Length > 0)
{
   query = query.Where( x => x.FirstName == firstName);
}
//...
```

Answer (score 5):

The following assumes Repository.Orders is returning an `IQueryable`, but the idea is just to dynamically add the expressions you need. The [execution of the query is deferred](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsBigONotationIssuesWithOlderNETCodeAndImprovingForLoopsWithLINQDeferredExecution.aspx), so you can build it systematically before actually asking for the results.

```
// You haven't executed the query yet, you can still build up what you need
var query = Repository.Orders;

if(orderNo >0){
    // You STILL haven't actually executed the query.
    query.Where(x => x.orderNo == orderNo);
}
if(firstName.Length > 0){
    query.Where(x => x.firstname == firstName);
}
if(lastName.Length > 0){
    query.Where(x => x.lastName == lastName);
}

// Even with this, you STILL aren't actually executing the query.
query.OrderByDescending(x => x.orderNo);

// You'll be executing and enumerating the results here, but that's OK because you've fully defined what you want.
return Json(query.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Repository.Orders.Where(x => 
    (firstName == null || firstName.Trim() == "" || x.FirstName.Contains(firstName)) 
    && (lastName == null || lastName.Trim() == "") || x.LastName.Contains(lastName)) 
    && (orderNo == 0 || x.OrderNo == orderNo)).OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderNo)
```

@Amit_g's example will work as well, and is arguably easier to read.  I like to do it all in one query.  It's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to AND these conditions and assuming your repository returns [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) (if not change it or add another overload or something)

```
var query = Repository.Orders

// Build where clause

if (orderNo >0){
    query = query.Where(o => o.OrderNo == orderNo);
}

if (firstName.Length > 0){
    query = query.Where(o => o.FirstName == firstName);
}

if (lastName.Length > 0){
    query = query.Where(o => o.LastName == lastName);
}

// Build OrderBy clause

query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.orderNo);

// Execute Query

results = query.ToList();
```